# Reading .docx files in Python to find strikethrough, bullets and other formats

Tags: python, pandoc, python-docx

Can anyone help me identify, in Python using python-docx, if a paragraph in a .docx file contains text that is formatted with strikethrough (ie. it appears but is crossed out), or has a bullet point at the start? I am trying to write a script to identify the structure in a document and parse the content.

So far I am able to read a .docx file and iterate over the paragraphs, identifying paragraphs that are bold.

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(r'C:\stuff\Document.docx')
for p in document.paragraphs:
    print p.text
    for run in p.runs:
        if run.bold:
            print 'BOLD ' + run.text
```

The rest eludes me for the moment.

Comment: You should be using something like [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the code you've posted? It isn't clear to me whether this does what you want or not.

Comment: Specific question is - how to find paragraphs that are formatted strikethrough, or have bullet points. Other formats would be useful too, but these two are most important

Comment: Apparently you were able to find paragraphs that are bold. Can't you use the same technique to find the other kinds of formatting as well? If not, please explain what you have tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: That is correct. Using python-docx it is not apparent what element of the Document.paragraphs structure shows the format elements of the paragraph I am looking for. But see my answer below. Looking for a pragmatic solution your Pandoc suggestion works fine for me.

Comment: Have you read: http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html re the `List Bullet` style?

Answer (score 4):

For strikethrough, you can just modify your example like so:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(r'C:\stuff\Document.docx')
for p in document.paragraphs:
    for run in p.runs:
        if run.font.strike:
            print "STRIKE: " + run.text
```

See the API docs for the [Font](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#font-objects) object for more fun stuff you can check.

Comment: thanks for linking the documentation about Font, this helped in finding the Length sub class used in python-docx

Answer (score 0):

Using a native Word DocX parser, rather than converting it to HTML and using an HTML parser, per the [Python DocX Docs](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html):

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
styles = document.styles
paragraph_styles = [
    s for s in styles if s.type == WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH
]
for style in paragraph_styles:
    if style.name == 'List Bullet':
        print "I'm a bullet"
```

Answer (score -1):

Following from the suggestion from mkrieger1 - I would suggest to use Pandoc to convert .docx to .html and parse the document from there.

Installing Pandoc is the same effort as installing python-docx and the conversion from .docx to .html worked like a charm using Pandoc. In .html the structure of the document I am parsing, and all format elements, is absolutely clear and thus easy to work with.

Comment: You want to perform a fairly trivial task using `docx`, which is in turn built on `lxml` - using a different XML format (like HTML) doesn't make the task easier but does make it more indirect. Have you checked out the `docx` source? it's pretty easy to work with if you've done any XML processing in the past.

Comment: I am slightly baffled by the -1 and your comment. Setting a breakpoint in the above Python code and looking at the paragraph object structure shows me no obvious way to determine if a paragraph is formatted strikethrough or with bullets. Several sites allude to complexities in the .docx format (apparently relating to backwards compatibility requirements in the file format) that obfuscate some paragraph formats. Using Pandoc gives me HTML that is as clear as day - strikethrough is <del> and bulleted lists are <ul><li>. Perhaps not pure and elegant but very pragmatic.

Comment: I upvoted the question, I just think this is a poor answer. You've tagged it `python-docx` and made an answer that's unhelpful to people using python-docx.

Comment: Fair point, I will correct the tags. So far the only answer that helped lead me away from python-docx. I don't mind how the problem is solved, as long as the solution works.

Comment: in pandoc you could also write a pandoc filter to modify the ast there... (instead of modifying the html). Although python-docX may work just as well for this specific case...